# Controller method skipping over return view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel

I am new to MVC and am dealing with ViewModels for the first time so I have been having a little bit of difficulty.

I have a view page where a user selects whether they want to harvest/transfer/dispose of a part. This data is then saved to a ViewModel. I then want to present the user with a summary page of what they selected. So I try accomplishing this by doing this.

On my POST method I try calling the summary get page

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SpecialOrderSelection(JobOrder job, ItemViewModel model)
{               
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      JobOrder jobOrder = db.JobOrders.Find(job.ID);
      if (jobOrder == null)
      {
         return HttpNotFound();
      }
      ViewBag.JobOrderID = jobOrder.ID;
   }  

  return SpecialOrderSummary(model);
}
```

This properly calls my summary Get method

```
public ActionResult SpecialOrderSummary(ItemViewModel model)
{
   if (model == null)
   {
       return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
   }

   JobOrder jobOrder = db.JobOrders.Find(model.ID);
   if (jobOrder == null)
   {
      return HttpNotFound();
   }

  return View(model);
}
```

Here is a snippet of the view page that I'm attempting to return

```
@model PIC_Program_1._0.Models.ItemViewModel
@using PIC_Program_1._0.Models
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SpecialOrderSummary";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ID)
    <h2>Special Order Summary</h2>
    <p style="color:red" class="noprint">Please review and verify </p>


    <h2>
        Transfers
    </h2>
    <h4><b>Components </b></h4>
    <table class="table">

        <tr>
            <th>
                IGT Component ID
            </th>
            <th>
                MFG ID
            </th>
            <th>
                Component Name
            </th>
        </tr>

        @foreach (var comp in Model.Components.Where(n => n.SelectedActionType == PartActionType.Transfer))
        {
            <tr>
                <td> @comp.ComponentId</td>
                <td> @comp.MFGNumber</td>
                <td> @comp.ComponentName</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

Here is my ViewModel

```
 public class ItemViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string MFGNumber { get; set; }
        public IList<ItemPartViewModel> Parts { get; set; }
        public IList<ItemComponentViewModel> Components{ get; set; }
        public IList<ComponentPartViewModel> ComponentParts { get; set; }
        public IList<ComponentSubCompViewModel> ComponentSubComps { get; set; }
        public IList<SubCompPartViewModel> SubCompParts { get; set; }

        public IList<SubCompSubCompViewModel> SubCompSubComps { get; set; }
        public IList<SubCompSubCompPartViewModel> SubCompSubCompParts { get; set;}

    }
```

The model is appropriately passed to the GET but it is skipping over my `return View(model)` and instead returning the 'Selection' View Page and not the 'Summary' View Page.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think the problem is that `View` implies the name of the view (cshtml) by the name of the function, and it MAY be picking up `SpecialOrderSummary.cshtml` as the view name instead of `SpecialOrderSelection.cshtml`

Comment: @Neil hmm if this is happening, how can I fix it?

Comment: return the View in the controller function, not in the subfunction.  It should be easy to prove that is the issue.  If not, I'll see if I can think of something else.

Comment: @Neil How do you mean? How would that look? Sorry I'm pretty new to this so I'm still learning but I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't how you do that:

```
return SpecialOrderSummary(model);
```

While this *will* ultimately call `return View(model)` from that other method, ultimately you are returning `View` from within `SpecialOrderSelection`, and the framework uses that to identify which view to render.

Instead of trying to trick the framework into calling a different action, redirect the user to that action:

```
return RedirectToAction("SpecialOrderSummary", new { ID = jobOrder.ID });
```

This will tell the browser to make a new GET request to `SpecialOrderSummary`, passing an `ID` value of whatever `jobOrder.ID` contains.  (I'm assuming that's the ID you want, if not just replace it with what you want.)

Comment: Thanks David, but will this return my viewmodel data? I have added in the view page I'm attempting to return, as the viewpage accepts 'itemViewModel' as the model so that is what it is expecting

Comment: @JoshFontaine: This is a good time to take a step back and examine what your controller actions are actually doing.  `SpecialOrderSummary` accepts a model instance, fetches a record from data based on the ID in that instance, then ignores that record and returns what was originally sent to it.  Which makes little sense.  I suspect `SpecialOrderSummary` should instead accept just an ID value, fetch a record from data based on that ID value, and return that record.

Comment: Yes, I'm just confused on how this works with ViewModel data, like I said this is my first time working with ViewModels so I don't know how it works in this case. Because when I don't pass in the entire viewmodel I get an error saying it was expecting a model

Comment: @JoshFontaine: Consider each controller action separately.  What do you want the action `SpecialOrderSummary` to do, specifically?  Conceptually I would expect it to receive an ID, get a record from the database, and return a view populated by that record, because that's very common functionality.  But what you *you* want that action to do?

Comment: Yeah but how does that work for a viewmodel? I understand how it works with databases but I'm just confused on how that works when the model isn't actually in the database

Comment: I just want the special order summary to have all of the data of the viewmodel so that then it will give a breakdown to the user of what they had done

Comment: @JoshFontaine: You're confusing yourself.  If `SpecialOrderSummary` needs an ID and fetches a record from the data, then that's all it should be doing.  When you direct the user to that action, you need only supply that ID.  It's not really clear to me at all what `SpecialOrderSelection` is supposed to be doing, and neither action appears to do anything meaningful with the models they're receiving.  So simplify.  What should `SpecialOrderSummary` do?  Should it accept an ID, fetch that record from the data, and return the view for that record?

Comment: I have included in my viewmodel. The 'selection page' is retrieving what the user chose for each component/part. The itemViewModel has an ID, but I'm unaware of how to fetch this with a viewmodel. As if it's not the entire ViewModel getting passed into the view I get an error that looks like this ```The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int32', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'PIC_Program_1._0.Models.ItemViewModel'.```

Comment: @JoshFontaine: You’re still overcomplicating things and confusing yourself.  In simplest terms, what should the SpecialOrderSummary action do?

Comment: fetch the data that the user submitted

Comment: @JoshFontaine: Should it get that data from the database?

Comment: No it should get it from the viewmodel

Comment: @JoshFontaine: So (1) it should return exactly what the user sends it?  That’s strange, since the user already has that information, but okay.  And (2) if it shouldn’t query the database then you should remove that logic from the method, as it only confuses things.

Comment: The selection page works like this. An item has components/parts and its components can have component/parts. Beside each part/component it has an radio option for the user to transfer/harvest/dispose. But this page can be pretty big and hard to keep track of so the summary page would just return what the user did. Example; Table of transfers would return all the parts/components the user chose to transfer. It's just so the user can verify everything. And then I will also be adding functionality where user can add additional parts and components to the order.

Comment: @JoshFontaine: Looking at the model in the question, that's a very large and complex structure to be passing around on a query string.  Even if the model binding works, that much data is likely to reach an HTTP 414 (URL too long) status pretty quickly.  It's worth reconsidering the design for that reason alone.  Since none of this involves any interactions with the database yet and you're just showing the user what they've selected client-side, you might consider simplifying the process and instead of posting a page just using client-side code to show the information.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions. Can you edit your answer to show me a little example of how you would do it? I really appreciate your time

Comment: @JoshFontaine: That's considerably more broad than what's being asked in the question.  Though at the very least the first thing you should do is remove the database code and references to `jobOrder` from the controller actions, since you say you're not using that information.  But for the question itself, the specific problem being observed is that you're returning a view result from the first action, so the framework is choosing the view associated with that action.  *Generally* one would redirect to the next GET action after a POST.  But your setup overall is... very strange.

Answer (score 1):

You're just confused with the view model. A view model has no special meaning. It's just a POCO (Plain Old CLR Object) that contains **ONLY** information you need to display on the view, not actions, not events. It serves as a container between controllers and views.

Again, I don't know the domain you're working on so the following is just my guess:

You might have already fetched the data from the database and construct this view model on the GET method. If you want to persist, e.x., the JobID, you need to declare a property there in the view model and put it in the hidden form in your view so that when the form is posting back, it's persisted.

```cs
public class ItemViewModel
{
    [Required]
    public int JobId { get; set; }

    public string ItemId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

You also need to specify the method and the controller your form is posting back:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("specialOrderSelection", "WhatEverController", new { area = "" }, 
    FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.JobId)
    <h2>Special Order Summary</h2>
```

Then on your POST method, it should only accept one parameter - the view model, as it's supposed to have everything you need:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult SpecialOrderSelection(ItemViewModel model)
{               
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      JobOrder jobOrder = db.JobOrders.Find(model.JobId);
      if (jobOrder == null)
      {
         return HttpNotFound();
      }

      // Do your logic to save anything you want to your database
   }  

  return RedirectionToAction("summary", new { jobId = model.JobId });
}
```

At the end it redirects to the action "Summary" within the same controller with a job id (or whatever key identifier to identify your objects). You fetch the data again with the id:

```cs
public ActionResult Summary(int jobId)
{
    // Fetch the data again with the ID, and fill the view model
    // ...

    var vm = new SpecialOrderViewModel
    {
        ...
    };

    return View(vm);
}
```

There you should have another view model and a view just for the summary page.

Comment: Thanks david! I'm just confused about the summary GET action method. How do I make it so that the vm is populated with the data that already exists instead of it creating a new vm?

Comment: You're not supposed to reuse the view models, if the pages are not highly similar or related. I would imagine the summary page will look totally different than the page you have to let users select parts.

Comment: Yeah its giving the users a summary of what is happening and providing them with an option to add parts/components. But it has to go through that entire process that the selection page went through? How does the view page retrieve the data if it's a new viewmodel?. The page will be relatively similar. All that's really changing is that it will be cleaner, it will show whats happening, there won't really be any user actions other than that the users will be able to add additional parts and components to the order.

Comment: Here is the thing: if 2 pages are highly similar, you might have done using AJAX from the beginning so that after the user has done the selection, the page doesn't need to refresh and the user can continue to add additional parts.

Comment: But the page is adjusting in format/ radio checkboxes are being removed, etc. So if it was to reload the same page I wouldn't be able to add in my changes. They aren't 'highly similar' but they also aren't 'totally different' so it puts me in a tough spot.

Comment: You might be able to just have one page for both then, and use AJAX to update user's selections, but without the details, I don't think I can help you look into it specially. And I know you're just learning now, it would be tough for you as well.

Comment: Yeah I just feel like I'm at a wall and I can't get past it.

Comment: I would suggest, once again, to read through the documentations first before starting coding..

Comment: I have, but yes there is so much to cover so it is difficult

Comment: Hey David. I just looked over your answer again. And was wondering, how would that even work? I know it should be a 'new' view model, but shouldn't it be a 'New' View Model consisting of the data we just used in the summary selection page?

Comment: I don't know. I don't have enough details on what you're working to determine what a summary page will look like. In my head (while guessing), I would have an area called JobOrder, and /jobOrder/dashboard/index?jobId={jobId} serve as the summary page to list all the job orders or a specific job order (JobOrder area, Dashboard controller, Index method), and /jobOrder/item/update/{itemId} to handle user selection updates(JobOrder area, Item controller, Update method).

Comment: Yeah thanks David! I appreciate all your time and effort you have used to help me. I think I'm going to try finding a way to simplify it, (Make a list of harvests/transfers/disposals) then in my specialorderselction post have it run through the model then add what the user selected to the appropriate list. Then hopefully I can pass that data to view instead of trying to pass the ViewModel around